# PHP 'copy' not working

Tags: php, copy

Can anybody tell me why this function isn't copying the file at all?

```
$pluginfile = get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/wp-content/plugins/supersqueeze/supersqueeze.php';

$urlparts = get_bloginfo('template_url');
$homeurl = home_url();
$urlstrip = str_replace($homeurl, '..', $urlparts);
$urldest = $urlstrip . '/supersqueeze.php';

function copyemz(){ 
global $pluginfile; global $urldest;
if(!@copy($pluginfile,$urldest)) {
        $errors= error_get_last();

    }
}
```

This file is run from `/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php`

I need it to copy the file at ($pluginfile) `/public_html/wp-content/plugins/supersqueeze/supersqueeze.php`

to ($urldest) `/public_html/wp-content/themes/[active wordpress theme]` - of course replacing [active wordpress theme] with the directory of the theme.

Comment: Remove @ and tell us what error you get

Comment: This is one of the places where you *don't* want to use the error suppression `@` operator. Unless you have a pro hoster with suexec/fastcgi-php, then it's probably a permission problem.

Comment: Why did you put "@" before `copy`? Remove it and you'll get exact error, not guesses.

Comment: Warning: copy(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/striking/supersqueeze.php) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 4
Array

Comment: @Jared: ta-dah. Is not it enough to solve your problem?

Comment: It sort of does. I now realize that I shouldn't use http:// in the URL, but if the script is run from public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php, does that mean the file to copy would be `../wp-content/plugins/supersqueeze/supersqueeze.php` if wp-content and wp-admin are in the same dir

Comment: I think you should have a look at WP_PLUGIN_DIR and TEMPLATEPATH constants. get_bloginfo('template_url') isn't what you need because it returns an url, not a path

Comment: That's what I was doing with the str_replace, replacing the homepage URL with .., it gives me ../wp-content/themes/activetheme/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have write permissions to `/public_html/wp-content/themes/[active wordpress theme]` as well as any other files you may be overwriting.

Comment: Wow come to think of it, I thought I edited the permissions but apparently I didn't. Thanks for reminding me! Lol.

Answer (score 1):

So, the second parameter to `copy()` must be a local file. Make sure it is also a writable destination (chmod) like webbiedave said.

```
$desturl = "./supersqueeze.php";
```

The reason is two-fold. PHPs http stream wrappers don't support POSTing or PUTing files, which a write-to action would require. Second, your webserver probably wouldn't support HTTP PUT either. (Though a small requesthandler script could handle such.)